# how to make tables in flutter using API

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-table

[image]

I need to show my data's like as above image in flutter. I don't have idea about ,So anyone can help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Take a look at [DataTable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html) in Flutter's API

Comment: you can also use [PaginatedDataTable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PaginatedDataTable-class.html) widget in flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// main method that runs the runApp.
  
void main() => runApp(SimpleDataTable());
  
class SimpleDataTable extends StatelessWidget{
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // MaterialApp with debugShowCheckedModeBanner false and home
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      home: Scaffold(
        // Scaffold with appbar ans body.
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Simple Data Table'),
        ),
        body:
        SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: DataTable(
            // Datatable widget that have the property columns and rows.
            columns: [
              // Set the name of the column
              DataColumn(label: Text('ID'),),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Name'),),
              DataColumn(label: Text('LastName'),),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Age'),),
            ],
            rows:[
              // Set the values to the columns 
              DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(Text("1")),
                DataCell(Text("Alex")),
                DataCell(Text("Anderson")),
                DataCell(Text("18")),
              ]),
              DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(Text("2")),
                DataCell(Text("John")),
                DataCell(Text("Anderson")),
                DataCell(Text("24")),
              ]),
            ]
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

1. Body Contain SingleChildScrollView used to Scroll Horizontally and Avoid Overflow due to Mobile with Low Screen Width.
2. SingleChildScrollView takes Single Child DataTable which takes Columns and Rows.
3. Columns represented in DataColumn that take a Label.
4. Rows represented in DataRow take Cells followed by DataCell that takes any Widget representing each Column Value of the Row.

Comment: thanks buddy, I need to call data from api ,how can i achieve that?

Comment: use to dio or http. dio is simpe and now used in.

Comment: see it bro. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75729257/which-is-the-best-way-of-api-call-in-flutter/75729314#75729314